# Turkish currency symbol not drawn in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unicode

I am trying to display the Turkish currency symbol (TURKISH LIRA SIGN) in my iOS app. For this I am using the [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ba/index.htm) as "\u20BA". This is working fine in iOS 7 but with iOS 6 the symbol is not displayed and I am seeing a square box being drawn. What could be the issue here?

I am drawing the symbol on my cell with below code:

```
NSString *aFormattedPrice = [myDict stringForKey:@"formattedPrice"];
aCell.detailTextLabel.text = aFormattedPrice;
```

When I put the NSLog on aFormattedPrice, it prints it correctly on console but cell detailed text label is not able to render it properly.

Comment: Post your code. Are you calling a `NSString` method to create the string?

Comment: Yes. I am using NSString *aFormattedPrice = [myDict stringForKey:@"formattedPrice"];

Comment: `- stringForKey:` is not a `NSString` method.

Comment: I know. Thats my utility method which internally calls valueForKey on my NSDictionary object.

Comment: I just tried this under ios 5.1, 6, and 7 it display properly for me in all environments.

Comment: Try using `+availableStringEncodings` to determine if UTF8 is available under your ios6 environment.

Comment: check out this https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836141 ios currency code TRL Turkish Lira (1922-2005) or TRY

Comment: When I put the NSLog on aFormattedPrice, it prints it correctly on console but cell detailed text label is not able to render it properly.